# What is the encoding used when exporting images as MOV with "VideoEncoding" -> "MPEG-4 Video"?

Tags: export, implementation-details, mac-os-x, video

I have a few rasterised images generated in Mathematica, and I want to output them in a video file, ideally using H.264 encoding. I found the following command.

```
Export["example_animation.mov", imSet, "VideoEncoding" -> "MPEG-4 Video"]
```

My question is, what is the actual encoding of the output MOV file? I know I'm telling it to use `"MPEG-4 Video"`, but that could mean a number of things. For example, is it MPEG-4 Part 2 or MPEG-4 Part 10? I'm generally quite confused about the relationship between MPEG4 and H.264 anyway. My impression is that MPEG4 Part 10 is actually a container for H.264, so could it be that the above Mathematica command is actually outputting an H.264 video in a MOV container? Or is it using an MPEG-4 codec that is different from H.264?

Comment: I'm using linux, not MacOS, so I can't answer fully.  But on my system exporting as an "AVI" file, using the setting `"VideoEncoding" -> "MPEG-4 Video"` has *absolutely no effect* on the resulting file.  The file seems to use no codec at all - just raw RGB.  With or without that setting, the filesize is exactly the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very empirical answer, so I hope that someone more authoritative will chime in, but here's what I found. I am on *Mathematica* 10.3.1 on Win7-64bit.

I generated a silly animation:

```
a = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "GiraffeFur"}];
b = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "CatFur"}] // ImageCrop[#, ImageDimensions[%]] &;
frames = Table[Blend[{a, b}, x], {x, 0, 1, 0.05}];
```

I then exported it to a MOV file using different options for `"VideoEncoding"` for comparison:

```
Export["movie noopt.mov", frames]
Export["movie MPEG4.mov", frames, "VideoEncoding" -> "MPEG-4 Video"]
Export["movie H263.mov", frames, "VideoEncoding" -> "H.263"]
```

I opened each file in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) to read the codec information it provides, and I obtained the following:

```
Export with no options --> VLC reports codec: Cinepak Video (cvid)
Export as MPEG-4       --> VLC reports codec: MPEG4 Video   (mp4v)
Export as H.263        --> VLC reports codec: H263Video     (h263)
```

Clearly the `"VideoEncoding"` option is working, but I still don't know what kind of MP4 encoding this is, which was the OP's original question.

[Wikipedia taught me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) that H.264 and MPEG-4 Part 10 are the same thing, so I decided to take the Cinepak- and MPEG4-encoded files from *Mathematica* and use [Handbrake, a free video transcoder](https://handbrake.fr/) to convert them to H.264 / MPEG-4 Part 10. I generated both MKV and M4v container files from Handbrake, then played them back with VLC to read off their codec.

VLC reported that the Handbrake-converted files used the "H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)" codec, thus differentiating them from the MPEG-4 files originally generated from *Mathematica*.

My conclusion is, therefore, that ***Mathematica* does NOT generate H.264 - MPEG-4 Part 10** video files when asked for MPEG4 encoding.

By the way, this is the list of encodings available on my system (MMA 10.3.1, Win7-64bit):

```
Internal`$VideoEncodings
```

> `{"Animation", "BMP", "Cinepak", "Component Video", "DVCPRO - PAL", "DV/DVCPRO - NTSC", "DV - PAL", "Graphics", "H.261", "H.263", "JPEG 2000", "Motion JPEG A", "Motion JPEG B", "MPEG-4 Video", "Photo - JPEG", "Planar RGB", "PNG", "Sorenson Video", "TGA", "TIFF", "Uncompressed", "Video"}`

Unfortunately, H.264 is not one of the options, as far as I understand them. This may be because H.264 is covered by patents and commercial use requires the payment of royalties, which Wolfram may not wish to do. However, *Mathematica*'s output files can be converted to H.264 through free tools (e.g. Handbrake mentioned above) *for non-commercial use*.

Comment: Wow I can't believe you went through all that trouble for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Ray You are very welcome!